# Clarity Datagrid - Trying to set a selection using cloned object does not work

Tags: angular, clarity

When using datagrid with single selection mode, after data grid is rendered - if we try to set the value for current selection by updating the variable that is bound to `[(clrDgSingleSelected)]`, the corresponding radio button does not get "checked" even when the object being set is equal by-value to one of the datagrid items.   The selection works only if the object is equal by reference to one of the items in datagrid.

Similar behavior is observed for both multi-selection when using `[(clrDgSelected)]`.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Take an clarity documentation example on data grid that displays list of users and uses "trackById".
2. In the component constructor, try to set the value for single selection, but use a cloned object.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedUser = {...this.users[2]}; 
    }, 4000);
```

In real life - one is not cloning the object intenationally - but one already has an object that one wishes to set as selection, and data grid just got rendered with new data from server and they all are newly created objects.  One of the objects in datagrid matches the to-be-selected object by-value, but not by-reference.

---

Stackblitz (Single selection issue): https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v2-dg-selection

Stackblitz (Multi-selection issue): https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v2-dg-selection-multiple

---

I did open a bug on Clarity (https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/4250), but it is mentioned that its a usage issue.

I am hoping that someone from Clarity team relooks at this scenario and proposes a workaround / fix.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue in our code too as clarity datagrid compares by-reference. I am taking following approach to identify selected objects from list:

```
import {   
  intersectionBy as _intersectionBy, 
  differenceBy as _differenceBy, 
  uniqBy as _uniqBy } 
from 'lodash';
```

```
private renewSelectedItems<EntityType>(datagridItemList: EntityType[], selected: EntityType[], matchProperty = 'id') {
    const currentGridSelected = _intersectionBy(datagridItemList, selectedItems, matchProperty);
    const selectedItemsNotInDatagridItemList = _differenceBy(selectedItems, datagridItems, matchProperty);
    const selectedObjects = _uniqBy([...currentGridSelected, ...selectedItemsNotInDatagridItemList], matchProperty);

    return selectedObjects;
}
```

I call this `renewSelectedItems` method whenever we refresh the grid data or selection change.

```
this.selected = this.renewSelectedItems(this.allItems, this.selected, 'id');
```

Hope this will help.